# Как сделать так, чтобы изображение выглядывало из блока с текстом

Tags: вёрстка, изображения, текст, overflow, блок

Пытаюсь сверстать сайтик по [этому макету,](https://www.figma.com/file/COFJnHB1lL47wFuw42t1Tx/Freebie_Coffee?node-id=0%3A2) но застряла на разделе "giftset". Скриншот того, как должно быть ниже

[image: Код дочки маминой подруги]

А у меня выходит вот так[image: Мой код]

и вот так (когда я добавляю position:absolute; к картинке)[image: Мой код]

Второй скрин больше похож на правду, но тогда летят к чертям отступы в контейнере.

Помогите, пжста, разобраться с кодом, чтобы все отступы были сохранены, чтобы изображение высовывалось из блока с текстом

```html
        <div class="container-gift">
            <img src="img/Mask-2.png" alt="bckgr" class="blue">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content-text center">
                    <p>Best Gift For Best Friend</p>
                    <h2>GIFTSET</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="gift-container">
                <img src="img/pr-0018-r.png" alt="gift" class="giftbox-img">
                <div class="gift-box">
                        <div class="gift-box-text">
                            <p class="price">285.000</p>
                            <h3>Giftset "Cà phê phin Việt Nam"</h3>
                            <p class="ingredients">Món quà tuyệt vời dành cho người sành cà phê. Hạt cà phê được Revo cẩn trọng chọn lựa, rang xay theo công nghệ và bí quyết học hỏi từ những nghệ nhân nổi tiếng, cùng với tình yêu, sự đam mê của người làm cà phê… tạo ra những tách cà phê tinh khiết chỉ dành riêng cho bạn.</p>
                            <div class="info-coffee">
                                <img src="img/coffee-beans (1).svg" alt="coffee">
                                <p>Loại hạt <br> Fine Robusta Blend</p>
                                <img src="img/mountain (1).png" alt="mount">
                                <p>Độ cao <br> 700 - 800m</p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="btn-line">
                                    <button class="coffee-btn">MUA NGAY</button>
                                    <p>CHI TIẾT</p>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```css
.gift-box {
 background-color:white;
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
.gift-container {
  display: flex;
}
.gift-box-text {
    padding: 65px 65px 75px 250px;
}
.gift-box-text h3 {
    padding: 12px 0;
}
.info-coffee {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.info-coffee p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.giftbox-img {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.container {
    margin: 70px 200px 130px;
    font-family: 'oswald';
}
.content-text p {
    color: #415167;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.content-text h2 {
    color: #415167;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```